# Apply Opaque blend mode to all object at once

Tags: materials

I'm using Blender 2.8, I don't know how to apply blend mode opaque to all object, which I got from another source.

Since it has so many object it's kinda tiring to apply it one by one. I've tried to select all objects in the viewport and/or in the outline (layer) and try to change them to opaque, but it doesn't work. Help :'(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just learned how to do this when trying to figure out an answer for you. Paste and run the code in the text editor after selecting all the objects you want to change.

```
import bpy

context = bpy.context

for o in context.selected_objects:

    o.active_material.blend_method = 'OPAQUE'
```

I made a little add-on to make a helper panel to do this, not very fancy but if it is useful then that is great. https://github.com/artistCDMJ/opacity_helper/archive/master.zip

Comment: I've using both, this code and the link you gave. the short one showing error msg "python script failed, see console", the link doesn't give any different.

Comment: Looks like the formatting changed with the website, let me fix - the second and 
 third lines need to be to the left under Import.Select all the objects, run the code and it should cycle through each and change the Blend mode to Opaque. If you install the addon, you need to install it as the zip file from the preferences panel and then look for the panel when in the 3d view when pressing N to bring up the sidebar. There I put options for each of the blend modes.

Comment: Also, you did a good job for making that :D